# Mostrar algo después del segundo item del RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

Tengo un `RecyclerView` y estoy aplicando `addOnScrollListener` para saber cuándo el usuario está haciendo Scroll y ha pasado el **segundo item** en pantalla para que aparezca un `FloatingActionButton`.

Código:

```
mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                if (mLinearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() != 0
                        && mLinearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() != 0) {
                    mArrowUpFloatingActionButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    mArrowUpFloatingActionButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
```

Ahora mismo, el botón aparece cuando el primer item desaparece en pantalla. Quisiera que el botón aparezca después del **segundo item**, en otras palabras, cuando el item en la posición 3 esté completamente visible, o cuando el item 0 y 1 hayan desaparecido (es lo mismo pero explicado diferente).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No logro dar con la fórmula correcta, alguna idea?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entiendo que la comparación la deberías hacer con el índice 2 que es el item que tú buscas y simplificaría la condición dejando que saliera el botón en el momento que sea visible dicho item:

```
if (mLinearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() == 2) {
    mArrowUpFloatingActionButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    mArrowUpFloatingActionButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Si eso te funciona, luego puedes ir jugando con la otra función por si te interesa que solo salga cuando esté completo el item